# Logical and of two functions

Tags: python

This is probably a silly question, but I haven't had any luck on google. I have two function with the same sort of input which output booleans. I'd like to combine them to form a new function. For instance, if my functions are `x` and `y`

```
def x(input): return input%3==0 
def y(input): return input%5==0 
answer = lambda z: x(z) and y(z)
```

I can do it this way, but is there a built in way to do it? I tried `answer = x and z` but that didn't work.

Comment: if you're doing fizzbuzz, you probably don't want to combine them :-)

Comment: Hint: If you want the function `y` to be used inside `answer()`, you might want to use it there. As well, you might want to check what your variable names mean and if you use them correctly. If the parameters of a function are like `input`, you might want to use `input` inside the function instead of `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

1. Unless you explicitly return a value from a function, it will return `None` by default. So, your `x` and `y` should have been like this

   ```
   def x(data):
       return True if data%3==0 else False
   def y(data):
       return True if data%5==0 else False
   ```

   Even simpler,

   ```
   def x(data):
       return data % 3 == 0
   def y(data):
       return data % 5 == 0
   ```
2. And then you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function like this

   ```
   print all(function(data) for function in (x, y))
   ```

   Now, `all` will return Truthy only when all the functions returns a Truthy value.